# don't know where to get data from vsCode autocomplete list

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm pretty new to writing extensions / platform programming. I'm trying to write an extension in vsCode that will filter the current intellisense types. For instance if you start typing the letter `let obj = a..` the intellisense will bring back everything in the global scope that matches it's intellisense. However I want to build an extension that will allow you to filter it by type so after typing 'a' you could press alt+i then p for properties or alt+i then c for classes and it will filter that list by the specific type.

I'm trying to read through vsCode api but it's difficult to understand where the handler/reference is for the autocomplete.

the API I found - [vsCode Website](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api)

so far I've come across the general workflow, so you would register a command in the package.json, then register the command in the activate export function, but I'm a little confused on how to implement the listener on change event of the intellisense and on how to get/set the intellisense info or if it's even possible at the current moment.

Answer (score 1):

For a general treatment on implementing auto-complete, take a look at the [Language Server example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server), particularly the section titled "[Adding additional Language Features](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server#_adding-additional-language-features)".